# A strange behavior about constructors in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

I show you the code directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
   public:
   A(const std::string& name){
    std::string aname = "HAHA_" + name;
    std::cout << aname << std::endl;
    }

    ~A(){
         std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

   size_t len = 5;
   char szTmp[30] ={0};
   snprintf(szTmp,sizeof(szTmp),"Getlist_V2_%zd",len);
   A a(std::string(szTmp));
   return 0;
}
```

The expected results are as follows：

```
HAHA_Getlist_V2_5
Done.
```

But It outputs nothing at all.  When I replace `A a(std::string(szTmp));` with
`A a(szTmp);` ,erverything is ok. It confused me for a long time.

Comment: Did you try `cout`ing the value in `szTmp` before calling the ctor to see what you actually sent into it?

Comment: Yes, I did. The value in `szTmp` is  correct, and  `std::string(szTmp)` is correct as well,so strange.

Comment: Your MCVE is missing `#include` directives. Otherwise, good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
A a(std::string(szTmp));
```

[This is a function declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), believe it or not! So, no `A` is constructed.

Instead, write this:

```
A a{std::string(szTmp)};
```

Or, since an implicit conversion to `std::string` exists, either of the following will suffice:

```
A a{szTmp};
A a(szTmp);
```

Comment: That initaializer list syntax will only work with c++11 - doubling the parenthesis (`A a((std::string(szTmp)))`) works on older compilers as well

Comment: Is `A a(std::string(szTmp));` the same as `A a(std::string);` or something else?

Comment: @clcto: Click on the link in my answer.

Comment: @Alec: We're on C++14 now. It shall be assumed unless a constraint is otherwise given. You'll note I gave a C++03 solution anyway. And that's not an "initializer list".

Comment: If it can be a function declaration, it is. This can be, so it is.

Comment: Good catch. Learned yet another oddity about the C++ language there.

Comment: @Lightness: Mostly just noting the version dependence, since c++11/14 isn't standard to most compilers.  Also, my g++ warns "warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11", hence my claim of initializer lists.  What's the correct term here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did, just was looking at the Timer example. I guess the part I was missing is that you can parenthesize the parameter names of a function.

Comment: @Alec [Uniform Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization)